# Democracy as a means for growth progress

Tags: democracy, political-theory, research-and-development

Is there any correlation beten democracy and development/progress.

If yes is it by data(interpolating democratic countries vs Human development index etc.) Or using deductive reasoning (conclusion from premises)

Comment: Can you define democracy and define progress/development? If we go back to Athens pre-Roman Empire then the answer will be no since all of their neighbors had better technology, military, agriculture, etc.

Comment: The body text question asks about a correlation (and there is one). But the title question seems to be asking about causation, which is much harder to establish.

Answer (score -1):

[LSE seems to think so](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/businessreview/2022/04/05/political-systems-affect-innovation/).
[image: Innovation and democracy].
Line comes from comparing 117 different countries based off of their democracy score and global innovation score.

Comment: see the contrast difference between China and India (outliers)

Comment: @quanity The line comes from using data from 117 different countries. Only 10 countries of interest were included on their graph.

Comment: correlation doesn't implies causation.

Comment: @quanity you litteraly asked "Is there any correlation beten democracy and development/progress" ... I have answered "Yes" there is a correlation... and now you are unhappy with the answer?

Comment: I am with happy withyour  answer but just pondering about causation...

Comment: Causation is property rights. We can see this best if you look in the video game industry. China has the biggest market for video games in the world., but they are the least innovative because they don't respect copyright laws. So people don't spend the time/money to create inovative games inside of china, because they know they will only lose money on it. WHile someone else steals their ideas/the game gets pirated into oblivion...

Comment: Autocratic regimes tend to have very little regard for individuals rights to own property/ideas. This makes individuals less likely to develop new/ creative ideas because they won't benefit from their work.

Comment: China sits as an outlier in innovation... Until you realize that China's extremely high number of patents, are mostly for things that were invented outside of China. And are being patented by someone stealing that idea because China doesn't respect foreign patents. I know someone whose entire career has been designing chips so that Chinese companies can't just copy paste the design.

Comment: What about India

Comment: 60% of Indians are agricultural workers. Additionally India spends .7% of its GDP on R&D... ANd it also lacks good copyright/patent protections, much like China.

Comment: I  think the real cause of innovation/lack of innovation happens to be the existence/absence of good patent/copyright protection. Which are usually strongest in countries with a high freedom index, and lowest in countries without... But India/Malaysia are exceptions to that rule.

Comment: innovation comes when you are able to fulfill basic needs first food safety electricity roads water shelter